# PYMQI return data type issue

Tags: django, python-3.x, ibm-mq, pymqi

I am trying the get IBM MQ Messages out of Queue Manager by reading the queue "SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.EVENT".

I am getting the following response when I print the message.

How do I convert the following message into a user friendly format after reading the queue:

> b'\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00$\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00c\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\tm\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x1fA\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00
>   \x00\x00\x0b\xe5\x00\x00\x033\x00\x00\x00\x0cnb153796
>   \x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x03\xf3\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00D\x00\x00\x0b\xe7\x00\x00\x033\x00\x00\x000ZANC000.YODA
>   \x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x1bY\x00\x00\x00
>   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x004\x00\x00\x0b\xe9\x00\x00\x033\x00\x00\x00
>   \x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x03\xf2\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x0b\xea\x00\x00\x033\x00\x00\x00\x1cMQ
>   Explorer 9.0.0
>   \x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x0b\xeb\x00\x00\x033\x00\x00\x00\x04
>   \x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x03\xfd\x00\x00\x00\xa1\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x1fB\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x04\xcd\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x03\xf1'

My code is as follows, I am using Python 3.6 and Django 2.1 everything is working fine except the format or the returned message:

Please assist in figuring out how to convert the returned message from PYMQI Queue Get into a user readable format:

```
    #
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import pymqi

#
queue_manager = "QueueManager"
channel = "Channel"
host = "hostname"
port = "port"
queue_name = "SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.EVENT"
user = "username"
password = "password"
connection_info = "%s(%s)" % (host, port)

#
#(option, args) = OptionParser



# Create your views here.
def index(request):
  #
  qmgr = pymqi.connect(queue_manager, channel, connection_info, user, password)

  #
  queue = pymqi.Queue(qmgr, queue_name)
  print(queue.get())
  messages = queue.get()
  #for message in messages:
  #  print(type(message))
  queue.close()

  qmgr.disconnect()

  return HttpResponse("MQ Hello Tests %s" % messages.hex())
```

Comment: Those are PCF formatted messages.

Comment: How do I get the correct format, like user readable format?

Comment: I would suggest googling for how to parse IBM MQ PCF messages.  There is a sample program provided with a the free IBM MQ client package called `amqsevt` that shows how to parse these in C.  Not sure if any good examples exist for pymqi.

Comment: Still can't get the correct format. Do you know how to set the format maybe using ptmqi.MD(), I think this is a Message Descriptor, sort of gives you an option to define the message type/format to be returned?

Comment: If you look at the pymqi samples there are some samples that process PCF messages returned from the command server, the event messages are in essentially the same format, so you should be able to get some idea of how pymqi can process PCF messages, in this case instead of them being replies from the command server these will be messages you read from the event queue.  Note there is a similar "issue" opened on the pymqi github for a user trying to read data from subscriptions to event topics in higher version of MQ (9.0.x for instance), these are also PCF, so maybe you can help each other.